# what are the meaning of these R notes

Tags: r

I read a R code on loess regression, here is part of it:

```
f.lo<- loess(bgs ~ f[,1], span=bw, degree=1)
bsln <- f.lo$fitted
```

What are their functions:  `bgs~f[,1]`  , the `~` and the `$` in the next line? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tilde `~` creates a formula, `$` extracts the `fitted` element from S3 object (so de-facto list) created by `loess`. You can find more details in [R-intro](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

mbq's answer is correct, but I'll just add this:

```
> `~`(y, x)
y ~ x
> class(`~`(y, x))
[1] "formula"
> terms(`~`(y, x))
y ~ x
attr(,"variables")
list(y, x)
attr(,"factors")
  x
y 0
x 1
attr(,"term.labels")
[1] "x"
attr(,"order")
[1] 1
attr(,"intercept")
[1] 1
attr(,"response")
[1] 1
attr(,".Environment")
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
>
```